# How to Insert String to add in subfolders name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help I am new in python. I have multiple files from different subfolder of a root directory with .wmv extension replaced with .mp4 and create a folder name base on the filename by removing other character starting at **'@'**. How can I insert the string 'DATA_' at the start of a folder name. All new created folders should starts with "DATA_". MP4 files will be moved in a new created folder name.

**example:**

```
Directory: D:\GE-J1N-2991   
Files found located at:    
D:\GE-J1N-2991\1-ZWC4\20160705051835547@DXV_Ch1.wmv    
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\20160705051836647@DXV_Ch1.wmv    
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\34-QWERD\20160705084433078@DXV_Ch1.wmv
```

**New created folder:**

```
D:\GE-J1N-2991\1-ZWC4\20160705051835547\  
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\20160705051836647\  
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\34-QWERD\20160705084433078\
```

**It should be renamed like this:**

```
D:\GE-J1N-2991\1-ZWC4\DATA_20160705051835547\20160705051835547@DXV_Ch1.mp4   
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\DATA_20160705051836647\20160705051836647@DXV_Ch1.mp4  
D:\GE-J1N-2991\2-QWD4\34-QWERD\DATA_20160705084433078\20160705084433078@DXV_Ch1.mp4
```

Code:

```
import os, glob, shutil, fnmatch

folder = 'D:\\GE-J1N-2991'
os.chdir(folder)

def locate_WMV(pattern, root=os.curdir):
    for path, dir, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)

for asf in locate_WMV("*.wmv"):
    os.rename(asf, asf[:-4] + ".mp4")

for f in locate_WMV("*@DVX_Ch1.mp4"):
    new_dir = f.rsplit('@', 1)[0]
    os.mkdir(new_dir)
    shutil.move(f, os.path.join(new_dir, os.path.basename(f)))
```

If i use this code, the folder is renamed but created in Directory: D:\GE-J1N-2991 which is wrong, it should be created in where the file was found

```
new_dir2 = 'DATA_'+ f.rsplit('@', 1)[0].strip()[20:]
```